# Prove: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\geq\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, rearrangement-inequality

> $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\geq\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$ where $x,y>0$

How should I approach this?

Comment: Try getting rid of the square root symbol by rewriting the inequality as ${u^2\over v}+{v^2\over u}\ge u+v$, with $u,v\gt0$.  Then clear the denominator and see if you can rearrange things into an inequality that's obviously true.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1996016/how-to-prove-that-frac-x-sqrt-y-frac-y-sqrt-x-ge-sqrt-x-sqrt-y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fleshing out a comment I left below the OP, I find it convenient to recast problems like this in a form that gets rid of the square root symbol.  In this case that's easily done by setting $\sqrt x=u$ and $\sqrt y=v$, which turns the inequality into

$${u^2\over v}+{v^2\over u}\ge u+v$$

An important thing to note is that we have $u,v\gt0$, since each variable stands for a square root (and appears in a denominator).  That means we can argue as follows:

$$\begin{align}
{u^2\over v}+{v^2\over u}\ge u+v&\iff u^3+v^3\ge u^2v+v^2u\\
&\iff u^2(u-v)+v^2(v-u)\ge 0\\
&\iff (u^2-v^2)(u-v)\ge0\\
&\iff (u+v)(u-v)^2\ge0
\end{align}$$

with the final line being clearly true since $u,v\gt0$ makes $u+v\ge0$, while $(u-v)^2\ge0$ even if the variables are allowed to be negative.

The basic argument here is no different, really, than in some of the other answers.  I just find it easier to see what's going on, and avoid making mistakes, if I don't have a bunch of square root symbols to keep track of.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying by $\sqrt{xy}$ (You can do this since $\sqrt{xy}>0$) you get
$$x\sqrt{x}+y\sqrt{y}\geq x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{x}\\x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})\geq y(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})\\(x-y)(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})\geq 0$$
Since we have that $x,y\geq0$ we are left with two cases $x\geq y$ which implies $\sqrt x\geq \sqrt y$

And $x< y$ which implies $\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{y}$ both cases are almost trivially true.

Answer (score 1):

multiplying with $$\sqrt{xy}$$ we get
$$x\sqrt{x}+y\sqrt{y}\geq x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{x}$$ and this is equivalent to
$$(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})(x-y)\geq 0$$
and this is true for $$x>0,y>0$$

Answer (score 1):

You can try using AM-GM for $x,y>0$.
$$
\sqrt{x} = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{y^{1/4}}\cdot y^{1/4} \leq
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{y}} + \sqrt{y}\right)
$$
and, in a similar way,
$$
\sqrt{y}\leq
\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{x}} + \sqrt{x}\right).
$$
Summing up the two inequalities you get the thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\sqrt{x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}$ and similarly for $y$ and you get:

$$\begin{align}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\right)-\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\right) &=x\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)+y\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right)\\
(x-y)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)\\
&=\frac{(x-y)(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{xy}}
\end{align}$$

You get, more generally, if $f$ is an increasing function on the positive reals, then:

$$\frac{x}{f(y)}+\frac{y}{f(x)}\geq \frac{x}{f(x)}+\frac{y}{f(y)}$$

Comment: And because $x,y>0$ we are done?

Comment: No, you need more than that. You need to show that $x-y<0$ iff $\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}<0$.

Comment: $x-y<0 \iff x<y \iff \sqrt{x}<\sqrt{y} \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}>\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} \iff \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}>0$

Answer (score 1):

By C-S $$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}\geq\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})^2}{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$$

Comment: What is the term C-S?

Comment: @gbox It's Cauchy-Schwarz.

Answer (score 1):

One more way, this follows directly from Rearrangement inequality...

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt y} + \frac{y}{\sqrt x} \geqslant \frac{x}{\sqrt x} + \frac{y}{\sqrt y}$$

Comment: But how does it prove the claim?

Comment: The RHS above in my post is exactly the RHS you want.

Comment: Ok, and then we get to Thomas Andrews answer?

Comment: Yes, after all the algebra used, essentially the rearrangement inequality is the same principle Thomas Andrews mentions in the end of his post.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}+\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}-\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}&=\frac{(x-y)(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{xy}}\\
&=\frac{(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2}{\sqrt{xy}}\ge 0.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $\sqrt{xy}$ both sides and with little algebraic manipulations you will get $(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y})(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})^2) \ge 0$  which is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**A detailed way of proving this.**

We start by multiplying through by $\sqrt{x} \sqrt{y}$ $ $ , which upon simplification, gives $$x\sqrt{x}+y\sqrt{y}\geq x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{x}.$$

So,
$$\Leftrightarrow x\sqrt{x}+y\sqrt{y} -x\sqrt{y}-y\sqrt{x} \geq 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x\sqrt{x}-x\sqrt{y}+y\sqrt{y}-y\sqrt{x} \geq 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) \geq 0.$$

But we don't know whether this last inequality holds or not (because it was derived from assuming your initial inequality was true). $ $  We can show this last inequality indeed holds as follows.

First of all, notice that the brackets always have the same magnitude, but can have different signs.  That is,
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}|=|\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}|.$$

Let's assume $ $ $y> x$ $ $.

(For simplicity's sake, which won't change the validity of the proof, as you'll see.)

Then it's true that $ $ $(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) > 0$ and $(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}) < 0$.

This means that in $ $ 
$x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) \geq 0$, $ $ the factors $x$ and $y$ are both multiplied by a number of the same magnitude.

Therefore, it follows that the magnitude of the first term $x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})$ is smaller than the magnitude of the second term $y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})$. $ $ That is,

$$|x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})|<|y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})|.$$

Then, since the term $ $ $y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x})$ is positive (because we assume $ $ $y> x$), it follows that
$$x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) > 0.$$

If $y=x$, then it's clear that 
$$x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) = 0.$$
So, as required, it is true that
$$x(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y})+y(\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}) \geq 0.$$

(Note that if we assume $x>y$ instead of $y>x$, then analogously, the above also holds.)